# GTM Trigger sequence

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How can I achieve this using Google Tag Manager?

I want Tag to fire if user made a seeuence of actions. For instance: visits homepage > visits certain category page > clicks on a button that expands additional content > having that content on screen visible at least 90% for 30sec or more > clicking on a button
... exactly in that order.

Comment: You might want to have a look at trigger groups: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/trigger-groups-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use sessionStorage to achieve this. By passing a value to the sessionStorage for each step in the funnel you want to track you can then trigger an event once the user reached the final step.

This solution will require some javascript skills. Here is code snippet to illustrate what I mean.

```
var url = 'https://www.startpage.com/second';
var start_page = 'https://www.startpage.com';
var second_page = 'https://www.startpage.com/second';
var third_page = 'https://www.startpage.com/second';

if(url = start_page){
   sessionStorage.setItem('funnel', 'step 1');
}

if(sessionStorage.funnel){
   var previous_step = sessionStorage.funnel;
   if(url === second_page && previous_step === start_page){
       sessionStorage.funnel = second_page;
   }else if(url === third_page && previous_step === third_page){
       alert('Send event');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My initial tought was to use session cookies, but I was looking for more “elegant” solution.

Comment: I understand you. However, in my opinion, I think that using pure javascript to achieve these kinds of solutions is more "elegant" than add a ton of different triggers, variables and tags in the GTM container. I hope you find what you are looking for, ciao!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to enhance Google Tag Manager (GTM) default behavior, buy making some information persistent. By default, GTM tracks information for the current page, so you need to keep track of users making progress in this funnel across several pages. You will find some good advice and examples in [this Simo Ahava article](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/two-ways-to-persist-data-via-google-tag-manager/).

Second, you need to create all the relevant triggers and tags, that catch these user actions, and update current user's progress in this persistent variable, when they proceed to the next stage. You also need to consider, if there are any actions, which reset the progress, or you allow the user to take other actions as well in the meantime.

The triggers are the following:

1. Page view for your main page
2. Page view for your specified category page(s)
3. Click trigger on the specified element to expand your content
4. A visibility trigger with proper settings (reference to element, 90% visibility, 30 seconds time on screen)
5. Finally, a click on your specified element

You should check the progress, and update it when the proper step is taken, compared to the current state. (E.g. complete step three only when user is already on step 2.)

Obviously, you'll need to write the necessary scripts within several Custom HTML tags, but you can probably generalize the behavior with some helper functions for checking the progress, and storing any updates.